# I want to find Whatsapp User name through php using Whats App API

Tags: php, whatsapp

I want to get user details like name, email and contact of a whatsapp user. Is there any kind of API by which i can do so?
I also wants to subscribe an user to a particular group in whatsapp and wants to send some message to the another whatsapp user.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [Philipp Heckel's blog post](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/07/send-whatsapp-messages-via-php-script-using-whatsapi/)